# Run Parallel and Sequential tests

Tags: testng, test-suite, parallel-testing

I have a setup where few of the tests are written to run in parallel and the rest of them are written to be run sequentially. We are moving from running these tests from run in sequence to run in parallel. Since we cannot move all of these tests at once, we need to be able to run these in both ways.
The tests written to be run in parallel are using different baseTest classes and different remote drivers. Can someone please suggest if there is a way to setup the testsuite in a way to run them both.

Thanks!

Sandeep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.  Setup two tests in the same suite xml eg.

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >

  <test name="ParallelGroup" parallel="methods"  >
    <classes>
        <class name="testngtests.TestParallel"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Sequential" parallel="false"  >
    <classes>
        <class name="testngtests.copy.TestSeq"></class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```